# Seek for perfect window manager

Tags: gnome, window-manager

Please help me find windows manager with these abilities:

1. Can be installed in Ubuntu, Gnome, compatible with gnome-panel.
2. Every window is maximized. If window can't be maximized, it's displayed on left top corner of desktop.
3. No additional panels are displaying. No title bar, no windows list.
4. Alt+Tab switches windows as usual and shows list of existing windows.
5. Alt+1,2,3,... activates n-th window.
6. Optional: ability to change sequence number of each window.
7. Optional: two workspaces.
8. High perfomance.

Which of window managers should I use? How to configure it?

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: For some of windows managers configuring like programming.

Comment: If by "some of us" you mean "you"...

Comment: i never used one myself, but this sounds like you are looking for a tiling window manager (ion3, awesome, …) i don't think they will work with gnome-panel though (and if you run gnome-panel you have to have the gnome libs installed anyway). to remove the window list, just right click on it and choose "delete this panel"

Answer (score 1):

Compiz would most likly work, due to the massive amounts of plugins. I do remember seeing one for using the number's to get to windows (I'm not in front of linux right now). For no Window bars, simply disable emerald or whatever window decorator it's using.

The only thing that I don't think exists is one that will force windows into the top corner just because thats useless.

And you can put compiz anywhere along with gnome-panel. Don't want a windows list for some reason? Just remove the applet.

Of course my natural question is why you want to remove so much usability and create such a strange interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/) in Monocle mode does pretty much what you want regarding full screen apps.
The keyboard shortcuts can be configured by editing the config.h header-file.